# How to println a string and variable within the same parameters

Tags: java, string, variables, printing, println

I am writing some code right now and I haven't done this in a while, how would I use the println function to write both a string and a variable?

I tried the following:

```
System.out.println("randomtext"var);
```

and

```
System.out.println("randomtext",var);
```

Neither of those seemed to work, what am I doing wrong? How do I do this?

Comment: try simple: `System.out.println("randomtext" + var);` - this will automatically call toString method of var object

Answer (score 16):

You either need to use + to concatenate, or use String.format to format a string or similar.

The easiest is to do concatenation:

```
System.out.println("randomtext" + var);
```

Some people often use `System.out.printf` which works the same way as `String.format` if you have a big messy string you want to concatenate:

```
System.out.printf("This is %s lot of information about %d and %s", var, integer, stringVar);
```

When using String.format the most important formatters you need to know is `%s` for Strings, `%f` for floating-point numbers, `%d` for integers.

More information about how to use String.format can be found in the [documentation about Formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).

Comment: There's never really any reason to use `System.out.println(String.format(...))` when you can use `System.out.printf`.

Answer (score 3):

You can concatenate the two strings together; the overloaded [`println` methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#println%28%29) take at most one parameter.

```
System.out.println("randomtext" + var);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println(String.format("randomtext %s", var));
```

Comment: Alternatively: `System.out.printf("randomtext %s%n", var)`

Answer (score 0):

System.out.print("The sum of two number would be: "+(num1+num2));

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please add some explanation to your answer. Especially since you are answering to a very old question that already has answers, tell us what is different or new about it.